# How to find out how much is the round off of a number?

Tags: c

I want to print out how much a number has been rounded off. This code is **incomplete** because I don't know how to do the process. 
Let's say the number is 311.88.
I want it to roundoff to the nearest 2 decimal which is the result will be 311.90. And for sure the roundoff is **0.02**. Now this is what I'm trying to achieve. I wanted to printout the **0.02** but apparently got no idea how to read the last 2 digit of the number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//VARIABLE DECLARATION
float total_amount, roundoff;

//INPUT
printf("Enter Number: ");
scanf("%f", &total_amount);

//PROCESS


//OUTPUT
printf("Roundoff: %2f", roundoff);
```

Comment: Just subtract...? Keep the original number, then round it, then subtract one from the other (either way around, depending on which you want the result to be relative to). You already know unconciously how this is done, so just think through it and translate that consciously to code.

Comment: How much is the roundoff of `PI` when written as `3.14`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's `PI - 3.14`.

Comment: @AdrianMole Indeed, but I guess the OP won't be satisfied with this.

Comment: good luck with the floating point computing and its inherent errors ...

Comment: @eugenesh 3.1 so the roundoff is 0.04

Comment: @MUFAMIN Sounds like we have different understanding of what "roundoff" is.

Comment: @underscore_d ah that's a solution, might work

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah I think so...

Comment: You also have a different definition of "nearest 2 decimal" from everyone else, it seems... `311.88` has 2dps already, and `311.90` is that rounded to _one_ decimal place.

Comment: @underscore_d well my mistake then, so sorry. it should be one decimal place

Answer (score 2):

Computing the round-off is tricky as the original value is not *exactly* 311.88.  `float` can exactly represent about 2<sup>32</sup> different values, 311.88 in not one of them.

Instead, 311.8800048828125 is used.  It is a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) of a power-of-2.

Like-wise a number rounded to the nearest tenth like 311.9 has a similar problem as the closest `float/double` to 311.90 is 311.89999389... or 311.8999999999999772...

The round off error to nearest tenth is not expected to be 0.02, but something close to that.

Code could simply subtract the 2 for a first order round-off error estimate (to 6 significant digits).

```
  float total_amount, roundoff;
  total_amount = 311.88f;
  double rounded_total_amount = round(total_amount * 10.0)/10.0;
  roundoff = rounded_total_amount - total_amount;
  printf("%.6g\n", total_amount);
  printf("%.6g\n", rounded_total_amount);
  printf("%.6g\n", roundoff);
```

Output

```
311.88
311.9
0.0199951
```

Comment: Was going to mention that if the domain on the numbers to compare is known, fixed point math makes this trivial without the FP representation fun.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Look forward to seeing your answer.  IMO, it is not a FP v fixed point issue so  much as encoding 311.88, 311.9 inexactness with a base 2 `float/double`.  With decimal FP, as may happen in next C, this is simple too.

Comment: Nah - Made it a comment only as a discussion point.  Your answer is more than sufficient.